# How to set child stl file position over its parent position in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Basically I have a one tray and over the tray I have added cube stl file and it is look like this

[image]

For cube stl position I used below code to set each cube position.**Right now I want to set cube position over the tray. To achieve this I need to calculate position of each cube stl file position. I am not sure how can I do it**. any help would be highly appreciated

```
mesh.position.set(
          10,
          15,
          20
        );
```

Here is the code that I am using to set object like this.

```
createScene(canvas: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>): void {
    // The first step is to get the reference of the canvas element from our HTML document

    this.jsonObject = {
      topic: '',
      id: 1,
      to: '',
      from: '',
      createdAt: 1578948378890,
      title: 'Manual load vis test',
      body:
        '',
      object: {
        backgroundColor: '0xffffff',
        height: 208,
        width: 1080,
        camera: {
          position: {
            x: 0,
            y: 90,
            z: 40
          },
          perspectiveCamera: {
            fov: 80,
            near: 1.5,
            far: 1050
          }
        },
        mainObject: {
          fileName: '5_lane_updated.stl',
          color: 14869247,
          scale: {
            x: 0.2,
            y: 0.1,
            z: 0.1
          },
          position: {
            x: -40,
            y: 25,
            z: -10
          }
        },
        products: [
          {
            fileName: 'cube.stl',
            color: 'rgb(20,40,255)',
            scale: {
              x: 1.1,
              y: 0.46,
              z: 1.5
            },
            position: {
              x: -42,
              y: 13,
              z: -10
            }
          },
          {
            fileName: 'cube.stl',
            color: 'rgb(75,255,20)',
            scale: {
              x: 1.1,
              y: 0.46,
              z: 1.5
            },
            position: {
              x: -8,
              y: 13,
              z: -10
            }
          },
          {
            fileName: 'cube.stl',
            color: 'rgb(163,228,247)',
            scale: {
              x: 1.1,
              y: 0.46,
              z: 1.5
            },
            position: {
              x: 25,
              y: 13,
              z: -10
            }
          },
          {
            fileName: 'cube.stl',
            color: 'rgb(20,40,255)',
            scale: {
              x: 1.1,
              y: 0.46,
              z: 1.5
            },
            position: {
              x: 60,
              y: 13,
              z: -10
            }
          },
          {
            fileName: 'cube.stl',
            color: 'rgb(255,51,20)',
            scale: {
              x: 1.1,
              y: 0.46,
              z: 1.5
            },
            position: {
              x: -42,
              y: 13,
              z: 25
            }
          },
          {
            fileName: 'cube.stl',
            color: 'rgb(255,177,20)',
            scale: {
              x: 1.1,
              y: 0.46,
              z: 1.5
            },
            position: {
              x: -8,
              y: 13,
              z: 25
            }
          },
          {
            fileName: 'cube.stl',
            color: 'rgb(250,150,255)',
            scale: {
              x: 1.1,
              y: 0.46,
              z: 1.5
            },
            position: {
              x: 25,
              y: 13,
              z: 25
            }
          },
          {
            fileName: 'cube.stl',
            color: 'rgb(50,168,82)',
            scale: {
              x: 1.1,
              y: 0.46,
              z: 1.5
            },
            position: {
              x: 60,
              y: 13,
              z: 25
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      priority: 1,
      type: 'manually_load_tray'
    };
    this.canvas = canvas.nativeElement;
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      canvas: this.canvas,
      antialias: true // smooth edges
    });
    this.renderer.setClearColor(
      new THREE.Color(this.jsonObject.backgroundColor)
    );
    this.renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    // create the scene
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      this.jsonObject?.camera?.perspectiveCamera?.fov || 100,
      window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
      this.jsonObject?.camera?.perspectiveCamera?.near || 0.1,
      this.jsonObject?.camera?.perspectiveCamera?.far || 1000
    );

    this.camera.position.x = this.jsonObject.camera.position.x;
    this.camera.position.y = this.jsonObject.camera.position.y;
    this.camera.position.z = this.jsonObject.camera.position.z;
    this.camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

    const spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
    spotLight.position.set(150, 150, 150);
    this.scene.add(spotLight);
    const loader = new STLLoader();

    loader.load(
      `${ApiUrls.GET_FILE}?file=${this.jsonObject.mainObject.fileName}`,
      geometry => {
        geometry.center();
        const material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
          color: this.jsonObject.mainObject.color
        });

        const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        mesh.scale.set(
          this.jsonObject.mainObject.scale.x,
          this.jsonObject.mainObject.scale.y,
          this.jsonObject.mainObject.scale.z
        );
        mesh.translateZ(10);
        mesh.translateX(10);
        mesh.translateY(10);
        debugger;
        this.group.add(mesh);
      }
    );

    this.jsonObject.products.forEach(product => {
      loader.load(`${ApiUrls.GET_FILE}?file=${product.fileName}`, geometry => {
        geometry.center();
        const material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
          color: product.color
        });

        const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        mesh.scale.set(product.scale.x, product.scale.y, product.scale.z);

        mesh.position.set(
          product.position.x,
          product.position.y,
          product.position.z
        );
        this.group.add(mesh);
      });
    });
    this.scene.add(this.group);
  }
```